# AWS compute optimized instance low multitcore performance

Tags: multithreading, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running CPU benchmarks (using CPU-Z) on 2 AWS instance types, c4.large and t2.medium. Both have 2 virtual CPUs.

On the compute optimized instance for single core performance the results are around 1400 points. For multi core performance results the score is around 1500. Since there are 2 cores, I'd expect the multicore performance to be around 1.5-1.9x of single core performance, it however is much less:

[image]

For the t2.medium instance the results are more inline with the expectations:

[image]

What can be causing this? Are the compute optimized instances hyperthreaded instead of actual cores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that the c4 vCPU counts correspond to hyperthreads whereas the t2 ones are physical cores. There are 3 things I could find pointing in this direction.

- The [virtual cores](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/virtualcores/) page lists t2.medium as having 2 cores for licensing purposes and c4.large as having 1 core
- The c4 announcement [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-new-c4-instances/) says

> In some cases, your workload might not need all 18 of the cores (each of which runs two hyperthreads, for a total of 36 vCPUs on c4.8xlarge)

- The [dedicated hosts](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/dedicated-hosts/pricing/) page says that you can allocate up to 16 c4.large instances on a physical host that has 20 cores